# Joomla Module Development - config

Tags: xml, content-management-system, joomla

I've been searching around for answers and couldn't find any.. Probably because I might have phrased it wrongly..

This is with regards to module development on either Joomla 1.5 or 1.6

Currently, I notice that the configs/params are declared inside modulename.xml

Is there a xml tag that will display a "browse" button, where it will allow the admin to browse for a specific file under a folder ?

Really appreciate with any help received :)

Comment: Just found this link http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_parameter_types

Am I at the right track ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the admin to be able to pick a file that is already on the server, this can be done in both Joomla 1.5 and 1.6 with the Filelist parameter. You determine which folder the list is generated from and the user simply selects the file from that list.

http://docs.joomla.org/Filelist_parameter_type

Comment: What if the folder I determined does not exist ?

Comment: The limitation of using Filelist is that the folder and the files you want to be available have to exist on the server. If you want users to upload files, then you have to use the File parameter, but that is only available in 1.6.

Comment: I am actually working with Joomla 1.6. Is there an example link you could show me for the File Parameter ? I checked the api for Joomla 1.6 .. not very helpful at all

Answer (score 1):

So far, I managed doing this by making a custom parameter type by extending the JElement class.

I managed to insert the upload button. However, I am still figuring a way to actually upload the file there itself.

This link might help you: **http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_custom_template_parameter_types**

Do let me know if you hit success in uploading the file.

Answer (score 0):

To display a browse prompt you need in html field with type='file'. That might help your search.